# Set Imageicon for JTree node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I created a `JTree`. I need to change icon for specific node. Able to `setIcon` for closed and open as well as leafnodes but I need to set icon for specified node in my `JTree`. Please shed some light on this.

Comment: so how do you set icon for closed and open?

Comment: tree=new JTree(root);  
         DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)tree.getCellRenderer();
         renderer.setClosedIcon(new ImageIcon("images/Video-icon.png"));
         renderer.setOpenIcon(new ImageIcon("images/Video-icon.png"));
         renderer.setLeafIcon(new ImageIcon("images/close.png"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to change the default Icon, you know this happens in the TreeCellRenderer.
You can simply implement a TreeCellRenderer of your own that has more advanced determining of the icon than the DefaultTreeCellRenderer.

Something like this :

```
public class MyTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private final DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private final  Icon specialIcon;

    public MyTreeCellRenderer(Icon specialIcon) {
        this.specialIcon = specialIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        defaultRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        if (needsSpecialIcon(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus)) {
            defaultRenderer.setIcon(specialIcon);
        }
        return defaultRenderer;
    }

    private boolean needsSpecialIcon(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        // check condition for special icon here
        return false;
    }
}
```

This basically delegates default behavior to DefaultTreeCellRenderer, but overrides the Icon if your special condition is true.

Comment: DefaultTreeCellRenderer extends JLabel. In the getTreeCellRendererComponent() it formats itself to be painted on the location in the tree (so it sets the text and the icon). And then returns itself.
My example simply uses all the behavior of DefaultTreeCellRenderer, but if the special condition is true it overrides the icon, using setIcon() that every JLabel has.